# Angular, how to get focus on clicked input after ng-click?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, input, focus

I have following input with ng-click.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="projectEntry.entry.defaultName"  class="form-control focusedInput" id="cwConnectorTeam" value="{{entry.defaultName}}" ng-click="test()"  />
```

And method  which should do focus:

```
$scope.test = function(elem) {
        $(".focusedInput").focus();
    }
```

How can I do focus on clicked item in AngularJS or jQuery?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: isn't it focus after a click ?

Answer (score 0):

In html markup use ng-click like this:

```
ng-click="test(this)"
```

And in your code use like this:

```
$scope.test = function(elem) {
        $(elem).focus();
    }
```

Comment: amazed! elem.focus() should work. I think there's something wrong with your another code...

Comment: Is it exactly, how you wrote your code.  If i tried $(".focusedInput").focus(); it gave focus on the last input.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
// MAKE INPUTS FOCUSABLE
        $(".focusedInput").click(function() {
            console.log(this);
            $(this).focus();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ng-click="test($event)"



$scope.test = function(e) {
    e.target.focus();
    //or $(e.target).focus()
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

but as @kalhano-toress-pamuditha has stated in his comment
[isn't it focus after a click ?] ^^